# Wrap text - case insensitive with php

Tags: php, search, variables, case-sensitive

If I search for `tOm ArNfElD` and the `$variable` is "Tom Arnfeld", I get great results form `LIKE` in MySQL (which is case-insensitive).

How could I wrap the matched text in the `$variable` with a `<span></span>` to highlight to what part of the search matched the query?  I need to retain the original case of the `$variable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$textToPrint = preg_replace("/({$variable})/i","<span class"myclass">$1</span>,$text);
```

this might help

Comment: grrr...someone else post it first while i was writing the answer

Comment: This is potentially bogus, you're not escaping (using `preg_quote()`) the `$variable`.

Comment: @alix : it's just a tip - next time i will provide more detailed tips/solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions:

```
$text = preg_replace('~(' . preg_quote($search, '~') . ')~i', '<span>$1</span>', $text);
```

There are other ways too, like the one [soulmerge suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119252/wrap-text-case-insensitive-with-php/2119281#2119281) (`str_ireplace()`):

```
$text = str_ireplace($search, '<span>' . $search . '</span>', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str_ireplace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) if you want to replace the whole string or convert your LIKE-parameter to a regular expression and use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (don't forget to [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) the string, though).

Example using regular expressions:

```
$parts = explode('%', $likeQuery)
foreach ($parts as &$innerString) {
    $innerParts = explode('_', $innerString);
    foreach ($innerParts as &$part) {
        $part = preg_quote($part, '/');
    }
    // always unset references when you're done with them
    unset($part):
    $innerString = implode('.', $innerString);
}
// always unset references when you're done with them
unset($innerString):
$regex = implode('.*?', $parts);
$transformedString = preg_replace("/$regex/", '<span>$0</span>', $stringToTransform);
```